# Not able to use new component in App component in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rect

I am trying to use resturant component in App component. I imported resturant in App but not able to use it.[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx7kW.png)

##Here is App component main##

```
import React from 'react'
import resturant from './components/basics/resturant'


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>This is App</h1>
      <resturant />
    </>
  )
}


export default App
```

##Here is resturant component.##

```
import React from 'react'

const resturant = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div>
        <h1>
            Yo I am resturant
        </h1>
    </div>
   
    </>
  )
}

export default resturant
```

not able to use resturant data in app component. In portal only App components data is showing.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? You are probably getting an error like this: 

Warning: The tag <resturant> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    at restaurant
    at App


React components should be upper case

Comment: You must start your component name with an upper case letter.